# TSQL Match Employee Assignments to Time Punch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table that designates employee assignments.
Null indicates current assignment:

```
|EmployeeNum|EmployeeAssignment|BeginDate |EndDate   |
|1003       |Analyst           |01/01/1990|02/04/2013|
|1002       |Coordinator       |05/14/2000|06/01/2013|
|1003       |Trainer           |07/28/2010|NULL      |
|1004       |Janitor           |08/09/2013|NULL      |
|1005       |IT                |09/02/2013|12/21/2013|
```

Another table designates time punches and paid hours:

```
|EmployeeNum| DatePaid  |hworked|
|1003       | 05/11/2013|7.5    |
|1004       | 09/01/2013|8.25   |
|1005       | 09/15/2013|5.45   |
```

Is there a method where I can use SQL to compare both tables to determine which assignment each employee had when they worked?

Comment: Yes, it is called `JOIN` :)

Comment: It completely depends on what you want to see. You say "which assignment each employee had when they worked" but that is completely shown by the first table.  So, either the answer is `select * from table1` or there is something else you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select t2.*,
       (select EmployeeAssignment
        from table1 t1
        where t1.employeenum = t2.employeenum and
              t2.datepaid between t1.begin_date and coalesce(t1.end_date, getdate())
       ) as EmployeeAssignment
from table2 t2;
```

EDIT:

You can also use `outer apply` to do pretty much the same thing.
Actually, given your data structure, an outer join should work as well:

```
select t1.*, t2.EmployeeAssignment
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.employeenum = t2.employeenum and
        t2.datepaid between t1.begin_date and coalesce(t1.end_date, getdate())
```

Comment: If more than 1 assignment were returned in the subquery, couldn't this return an error?  Wouldn't a `join` be better with this included in the `on` criteria?  Perhaps your assumptions are that an employee can only hold one position during a single pay period (perhaps)...

Comment: @user2480596 . . . You can put `top 1` in the subquery to get only one row.  More importantly, though, the employee assignments are presumably *intended* to have one at any given time.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.employeenum = t2.employeenum
```

Just SELECT whatever you want in your query